# XCheckWindowEvent doesn't return ClientMessage events

Tags: c++, c, x11

I'm playing around with xlib, and I've got something like this to check for events on a window/sub-window basis:

```
// Dispatch X11 events in a more friendly format
static inline bool xwin_event(xwin_t *xwin, event_t *evt) {
    XEvent event;
    if (!XCheckWindowEvent(xwin->xconn->dpy, xwin->window, 0xFFFFFFFF, &event)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (event.type == ClientMessage) {
        printf("Got event, wid: %i\n", event.xany.window);
    }
}
```

Which I call in a loop.  I'm building my window thusly:

```
// Define events we want
XSelectInput(xconn->dpy, xwin->window,
             KeyPressMask        | 
             ButtonPressMask     | ButtonReleaseMask |
             EnterWindowMask     | LeaveWindowMask   |
             PointerMotionMask   | ExposureMask      |
             StructureNotifyMask | SubstructureNotifyMask);

// Grab some window manager events
xwin->proto = XInternAtom(xconn->dpy, "WM_PROTOCOLS",     1);
xwin->close = XInternAtom(xconn->dpy, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 0);
XSetWMProtocols(xconn->dpy, xwin->window, &xwin->close, 1);
```

And for some reason, I'm never seeing any ClientMessage events come out of the queue.  If I check with something like this (which doesn't let me filter by window):

```
if (!XPending(xwin->xconn->dpy)) {
    return false;
}

XNextEvent(xwin->xconn->dpy, &event);
```

It comes through just fine.  Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the man page for `XCheckWindowEvent` explicitly says that

> XCheckWindowEvent() cannot return ClientMessage, MappingNotify, 
>   SelectionClear, SelectionNotify, or SelectionRequest events because
>   these event types are by definition unmaskable.

Comment: Well damn, I've been reading the documentation at http://tinyurl.com/7ywhvbn, which is obviously incomplete, thanks!

Comment: The man page on my system does not say that. Also, how do you get a `ClientMessage` event without blocking then?